# Adding HTML Tags to UI in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an application that displays a generated table in ASP.NET MVC. The code to generate the table is this:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div class="form-inline">
            <br />
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ViewModel>()
              .Name("name")
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(c => c.c1);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.c2);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.c3);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.c4);
                  columns.Bound(c => c.c5);
              }
              )
              .
              .Sortable()
              .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
              .Navigatable()                  
              .DataSource(ds => ds
                .Ajax()
                .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAddress", "Home"))
               )
        )
        </div>
    }
```

The table generated by the application looks good. This is how it looks in HTML

```
<table role="grid" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="natipgrid_active_cell" > ... </table>
```

The table is having accessibility issues for screen reader and I need to add a summary tag to the HTML table. So it comes out like this

```
<table summary="Summary of contents of the table" role="grid" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="natipgrid_active_cell" > ...</table>
```

How can I add HTML summary tag to the Grid? It doesn't have to be a summary tag, it can be a state or property tag as well. Anything that helps call out the table for screen readers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the data binding event after reading data and add whatever attribute you want using javascript, for example

```
.Read(read => read.Action("ReadAddress", "Home").Data("onDataBinding"));
<script>
     function onDataBinding() {
         $('name > table').attr('summary', 'Summary of contents of the table');
     }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it, it did not work. Still the same <table role="grid" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="natipgrid_active_cell" >

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding the HtmlAttributes to the grid, see below.

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-inline">
        <br />
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.ViewModel>()
          .Name("name")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { summary = "Summary of table contents" }) <--------- here
          .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(c => c.c1);
              columns.Bound(c => c.c2);
              columns.Bound(c => c.c3);
              columns.Bound(c => c.c4);
              columns.Bound(c => c.c5);
          }
          )
          .
          .Sortable()
          .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
          .Navigatable()                  
          .DataSource(ds => ds
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("ReadAddress", "Home"))
           )
    )
    </div>
}
```